# Windows Phone 8 Application Name

Tags: windows-phone-8

I recently got an application made and have received the source code. However the name on the game is wrong, and when I asked the guy to change it he demanded an extra 100 USD to change just the name of the application. I'm wondering is there anyway I can change the app within the source code, or when I submit the app to the store?

Comment: There's a title stored in the app manifest. [see MSDN for more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff769509(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_APPelement)

Comment: if you havent figured out it yet, you can contact me, and I can help change it for you.. anyway, it should be in the app manifest, if there is no special graphic element which includes name of your game...

Answer (score 0):

If you have the source code and the account to subit it to the store you are in control however...

There might be more to it than just the name in the manifest, there could be:

- art (graphics),
- hard coded references to the assembly (e.g., xaml namespaces)
- documentation (manuals)
- a website (ads)

that need changing too.

To figure this out you need to get to know the application, make the changes and test them. Depending on your expertise it might be cheaper to pay.